# Have Selenium Chrome driver launch the "real" Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When an application running Selenium uses the Chrome driver, it launches a standalone version of Chrome that doesn't in any way relate to the Chrome using the primary profile, that is the one that contains our search history, passwords, cookies, etc.

Is there a way to tell the Chrome driver to launch the "real" Chrome and not a standalone version? I imagine this could potentially be a security flaw, but I'd like to know.

Comment: There is a "profile" section of selenium.  You may look into using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After investigating for a little while I found out that it's possible to provide the ChromeDriver object with information about the User Data folder used by Chrome by sending it as an argument in the `ChromeOptions` object like so:

Example in Java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/[UserName]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This opened the "real" Chrome using all our settings.

Comment: Please be aware...the reason that the driver opens Chrome with a 'virgin' profile is to help make your tests more robust.  If a user manually changes Chrome settings that will impact your application under test, you may experience unexplained behavior of your tests.  Debugging situations like this can REALLY suck up time that you would rather spend writing new tests.  I recommend that you identify the settings that your tests really need and incorporate those in your ChromeOptions object directly, rather than using them from this user's profile.

Comment: To select a different profile, say Profile 1, use

options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 1");